# Bottom sheet margin top not working correctly - Android

Tags: android, xml, material-design, bottom-sheet, material-components-android

I am working with bottom sheet and it is working great if I dont add margin top.

I want the bottom sheet to fill the screen when pulled up but it also goes behind the Action Bar.
To solve this, I added margin top to the bottom sheet equivalent to the height of action bar, it works great until bottom bar is back to bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:margin_top="60dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_camera">
```

When bottom sheet is slided down, margin is no more there and view above the screen becomes equal to peekHeight + marginTop

**Before Expanded**

[image: How should I fix it?]

**Collapsed after expanding once**

[image]

Comment: please put image what you want to achieve

Comment: @AbhijitChakra added photo

Comment: It looks like bug, i'm going to report it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a `Toolbar` instead of adding a margin to the BottomSheet. You can put this inside the `CoordinatorLayout` at the top so it will be behind the BottomSheet. Make sure the View that has the `BottomSheetBehavior` is at the bottom of the layout and that it has a higher elevation than the `Toolbar`.

Comment: like that, the bottomSheet will go over toolbar, and the requirement is to be under the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to change the root layout - from **CoordinatorLayout** to any other (Relative/Linear and so on). And after that you can add your CoordinatorLayout in your new root ViewGroup with desired marginTop.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
```